# How to write things in scr?

Tags: html

I am just learn html and beginner.I don't know what I write in src.example-src="???".I already know src is image and alt is the caption when image can't be display.I mess with it for 3 days.so,someone explain me .Thank you

I tried  images at google but nothing appear.

Answer (score 0):

if the image is in the same folder that your html file is you should just write the name and type of your image like that:

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" alt="ball">
<img src="myimage.png" alt="ball">
<img src="myimage.bmp" alt="ball">
...
```

if the image is in a folder where your html file is you should write the folder name then /
like that:

```
<img src="foldername/myimage.jpg" alt="ball">
<img src="foldername/myimage.png" alt="ball">
<img src="foldername/myimage.bmp" alt="ball">
...
```

if the image is in the Previous folder you should use that ../
like that:

```
<img src="../foldername/myimage.jpg" alt="ball">
<img src="../foldername/myimage.png" alt="ball">
<img src="../myimage.bmp" alt="ball">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`src` is an attribute that can be used in the `<img>` tag in html which can be used to specify the source(URL) of the image. An example of an `<img>` tag that uses a source would be this:

```
<img src="path/to/image.jpg" alt="Description of the image">
```

If you want to use a google image you could go to google, copy an image url and paste that in the `src` like so: `src="google.com/image.jpg"`. I would not recommend doing this though since you have no control over the image availablity when it is on an external host (like google). Also make sure you have the necessary permissions or follow any usage guidelines set by the image owner.

Much more information and examples can be found here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_src.asp